# Why the loss of NN doesn't change?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

**First of all**, when try to implementing GAN, I found loss in code below doesn't change, Here is the code with the respective input aside:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import os


def sample_z(m, n):
    return np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=[m, n])


def generator(z, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("generator", reuse=reuse):
        w_init = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
        dense1 = tf.layers.dense(z, 128, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_init)
        o = tf.layers.dense(dense1, 784, activation=tf.nn.tanh, kernel_initializer=w_init)
        return o


def discriminator(x, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("discriminator", reuse=reuse):
        w_init = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
        dense1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 128, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_init)
        dense2 = tf.layers.dense(dense1, 1, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_init)
        o = tf.nn.sigmoid(dense2)
        return o, dense2


def plot(samples):
    ...


z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 100], name='z')
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name='x')
isTrain = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool)
G_sample = generator(z, isTrain)

D_real, D_logit_real = discriminator(x)
D_fake, D_logit_fake = discriminator(G_sample, reuse=True)

D_loss_real = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D_logit_real, labels=tf.ones_like(D_logit_real)))
D_loss_fake = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D_logit_fake, labels=tf.zeros_like(D_logit_fake)))
D_loss = D_loss_real + D_loss_fake
G_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D_logit_fake, labels=tf.ones_like(D_logit_fake)))

T_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
D_vars = [var for var in T_vars if var.name.startswith('discriminator')]
G_vars = [var for var in T_vars if var.name.startswith('generator')]
D_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(D_loss, var_list=D_vars)
G_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(G_loss, var_list=G_vars)

batch_size = 128
z_dim = 100
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('mnist/', one_hot=True)
i = 0

if not os.path.exists('output/GAN/'):
    os.makedirs('output/GAN/')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for it in range(100000):
        x_batch, _ = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

        _, D_loss_curr = sess.run(
            [D_solver, D_loss],
            feed_dict={x: x_batch, z: sample_z(batch_size, z_dim), isTrain: True}
        )
        _, G_loss_curr = sess.run(
            [G_solver, G_loss],
            feed_dict={z: sample_z(batch_size, z_dim), isTrain: True}
        )

        if it % 1000 == 0:
            samples = sess.run(G_sample, feed_dict={z: sample_z(16, z_dim)})
            fig = plot(samples)
            plt.savefig('output/GAN/{}.png'.format(str(i).zfill(3)), bbox_inches='tight')
            plt.close(fig)
            i += 1

            print('Iter: {:4} D_loss: {:.4} G_loss: {:.4}'.format(
                it, D_loss_curr, G_loss_curr))
```

The output is like this:

```
Iter:    0 D_loss: 1.379 G_loss: 0.6931
Iter: 1000 D_loss: 0.6937 G_loss: 0.6931
Iter: 2000 D_loss: 0.6933 G_loss: 0.6931
Iter: 3000 D_loss: 1.386 G_loss: 0.6931
Iter: 4000 D_loss: 1.386 G_loss: 0.6931
Iter: 5000 D_loss: 1.386 G_loss: 0.6931
```

**Specially**, when I changed the function 'generator' and 'descriminator' to below, the loss changes.

```
def generator(z, isTrain, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("generator", reuse=reuse):
        w_init = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
        dense1 = tf.layers.dense(z, 128, kernel_initializer=w_init)
        relu1 = tf.nn.relu(dense1)
        dense2 = tf.layers.dense(relu1, 784, kernel_initializer=w_init)
        o = tf.nn.tanh(dense2)
        return o


def discriminator(x, isTrain, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("discriminator", reuse=reuse):
        w_init = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
        dense1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 128, kernel_initializer=w_init)
        lrelu1 = lrelu(dense1, 0.2)
        dense2 = tf.layers.dense(lrelu1, 1, kernel_initializer=w_init)
        o = tf.nn.sigmoid(dense2)
        return o, dense2
```

Can someone tell my why this happened, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `reuse` parameter must be `True` or `False` or `None` in
   `tf.variable_scope` that `G_sample = generator(z, isTrain)` will
   unavoidably raise error.
2. Since there is NO dropout, batch normalization ... layer in model,
   `isTrain` is not necessary.
3. we reuse discriminator networks with different inputs by `tf.variable_scope`, 
   when `reuse` is true, we use created variable with same name instead of create one.  cf.
   [Intro_to_GANs_Solution.ipynb](https://render.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?commit=35ad0789cfb4a5d91e9adf8000f0b42be6d37c3b&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f756461636974792f646565702d6c6561726e696e672f333561643037383963666234613564393165396164663830303066306234326265366433376333622f67616e5f6d6e6973742f496e74726f5f746f5f47414e735f536f6c7574696f6e2e6970796e62&nwo=udacity%2Fdeep-learning&path=gan_mnist%2FIntro_to_GANs_Solution.ipynb&repository_id=78865098&repository_type=Repository#Variable-Scope)
4. It does not matter whether add activation implicitly in dense layer or explicitly call `tf.nn.relu` `tf.nn.tanh`